# Javascript column selection box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a common selector box but I have no idea what they are actually called.

The selection box has two columns listing columns and the user can move elements from each list into the other by using a left arrow or right arrow in the center of the box.

Can anyone provide an example or point me towards a relative article?

Here is a potato quality version of what im talking about
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about jQuery UI suit? Like https://jqueryui.com/droppable/ ?

Comment: Hi dizzytri99er, please provide more detail and code if possible.

Comment: I have attached an image of what i mean. Two columns of elements and two buttons in the middle that allow you to move elements from side to side. I know its a common selector but I cannot work out what they are called

Comment: Also @Justinas, thanks for the suggestion but thats not what I Require. I just needa way to move elements from one side of the list to the other

Comment: @dizzytri99er What are the nature of your information?

Comment: I was creating a modal to toggle the visibility of columns on a page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search about "jquery picklist".

These are links :

- [JQuery picklist](https://plugins.jquery.com/picklist/)
- [Jquery picklist demos](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/wiki/Demos)
- [Google demo](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/)